# Caesar's Cipher in C

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to do a program that receives an array of characters as input and each letter is replaced by another. On the following code, I only consider one change ('a'-->'h'), but as soon as the program works for that change, I will implement the others (based, for example in Caesar's Cipher). 
The thing is that the program compiles successfully, however, when I run it, if I insert an 'a', he return another 'a' (and it was supposed to return an 'h'). 
What is wrong with the code?
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ciphering (char text[])
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i!='\0'; i++)
    {
         if (text[i]>='a' && text[i]<='z')
         {
                  if (text[i]=='a')
                      text[i]='h';
         }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char text[1000];

    scanf("%s", text);
    ciphering(text);
    printf("%s\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This line `for (i=0; i!='\0'` is incorrect.  `'\0'` is `0`.  It should be `for (i=0; text[i]!='\0'`.

Comment: Instead of `scanf("%s", text);`, you should use `fgets( text, sizeof ( text ), stdin );` for safety...  it guarantees no more than sizeof text is ever read, preventing potential memory errors.... it is a good habit to get into, errors like that are what hacker exploits are made from.

Comment: @JohnH Thank you for your suggestion. It actually solved another problem on my code (program was stopping when whitespace's were inserted).

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop in the function has

```
for(i = 0; i != '\0'; ++i)
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Change it to:

```
for(i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
```

because you want to check when the `text[i]` has a `NUL` character.

Answer (score 1):

`0` and `'\0'`, in the context of your for loop (and many other contexts) are the same.

```
for(i = 0; i != '\0'; ++i)
```

I read that as: "for i from zero while it's different than zero ..." which effectively means the loop will not run even a single time.

Comment: Apparently, the loop will run *infinitely*.

Comment: @volerag: it will not run. Not once, let alone an infinite number of times.

Comment: I think `i` would never be `\0` which makes `i != '\0'` true, hence infinite?

Comment: The assignment `i = 0` makes it zero. Then the comparison `i != '\0'` yields false ... the increment is never executed

Comment: I may be wrong, but `0 != '\0'` is true, right? *Zero is not equal to null character? True.*

Comment: Ah! I see your problem now. But `0` and `'\0'` are absolutely identical (except in source form): the first is an integer literal with type `int` and value `0`; the second is a character literal with type `int` and value `0`.

Comment: Oh! I am so sorry, I didnt know even a basic difference in C. @pmg I'm really sorry. Thanks a lot for taking the time to convince me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The program does not enter into the `for()` loop because the continuation condition is false:

```
for (i = 0; i != '\0'; i ++) {
```

What you need to test is that `i` (the index of the character currently analyzed) does not point to the null character. That line should read:

```
for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i ++) {
```